# Redirect to a controller and pass a value to its function

Tags: angularjs, controller

Suppose I have a function in my controller and a variable. And there's another controller with another function that takes a variable as parameter.

I need to redirect to that controller from my controller, call that function, and pass variable value from my controller.

How can I do this in a single page application?

Its a lot like when we redirect from one page to another in MVC and pass a value through URL. I'm trying to pass a variable to another controller that has its own page.

Comment: Are you trying to do this between two states? Or between two controller that happen to be active on the same page, ie one page controller and another controller on a directive on that page.

Comment: no they're totally different independent controllers with different pages. not states but controllers..

Answer (score 3):

You can do it two ways.
One is through **angular services** and other is via **ui-routing resolve** functionality.
**Services** are more preferable according to best practices standards.

Comment: I agree with ahmer the services is probably the best way to do this.

Comment: I'll check them. But a basic set of instructions would've been nice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$routeParams` to get the behavior similar to MVC. Just define a route like this:

```
    {
        url: '/page/:pageNo',
        config: {
         templateUrl: "page.html",
         controller: "pageController"
        }
    }
```

From the controller you want to redirect from, use `$location.path`

```
$location.path('/page/' + $scope.pageNo);
```

Finally, in the controller where you redirect to, you will access this param using `$routeParams`

```
$routeParams.pageNo
```